# Number of data points needed to estimate the $nth$ moment of a distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, moments

Assuming that I do not know much about an underlying distribution. How many data points does one needs to estimate the $n$th moment?

Is there a formula for the $n$th moment? Is there also formulas for the confidence interval of these parameters?

If a general formula for $n$th moment is difficult to determine, what do we know about the lower order ones (as far as the number of points needed for estimation) (e.g the first four)?

Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you are assuming about the distribution: zero are needed if you assume values for the moments and one in all other cases.  Likewise, obtaining confidence limits depends on your distributional assumptions.  Estimating the moments also depends on what properties you require of the estimator; for instance, there are different estimators of the fourth moment depending on whether you want it to be unbiased.

Comment: Assuming that I do not really know the underlying distribution, can we still estimate the number of points needed ?

Comment: One is the minimum.  Obviously it's not a very useful minimum, but to go any further you need to develop a sense of how variable that estimate might be. That requires larger samples. For moments higher than the first, it is crucial to narrow the possible distributions as much as possible, because they tend to be *extremely* variable.  This is a much larger subject than might appear--consider, after all, that it covers all the methods of estimating a mean and is closely connected with methods of estimating variances; and that's just the beginning!

Comment: About 25 years ago I think I saw John Tukey cited as saying off the cuff something with roughly this flavour: you need $10^k$ data points to get a half-way decent estimate of the $k$th moment. (Don't quote me on this: all I trust myself to remember was that the rule of thumb was *very discouraging*.) I've been hoping to rediscover the reference for about 20 years.

Comment: Either after of before deciding on statistical structure to characterize the quality of an estimator, you'll also need to justify how good it needs to be for your application.  To think that there's an answer out there irrespective of the subject matter and objective is common but naive.  Should one use the same sample size rule for estimation issues associated with brain surgery, baking bread, testing for antibodies, etc. ?

Answer (score 7):

The raw moments $\mathbb E[X^k]$ all admit unbiased estimators based on an iid sample of size $n$ from the distribution behind the expectation, as for instance$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k$$

As demonstrated in the final page reproduced below Paul Halmos wrote a now [famous paper in 1946, called the theory of unbiased estimation](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177731020), where he gives necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of unbiased estimators of some expectation based on an iid sample of size $n$ from the distribution behind the expectation.

In particular, he studies the existence of *unbiased* estimators of the $k$-th centred or central moments$$\mu_k=\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E\{X\})^k]$$for which he shows

1. that they only exist when $k\le n$
2. that they can only be expressed as a rescaling of the empirical moment$$\hat\mu_k^n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X}_n)^k= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\hat\mu_1^n)^k$$when $k\le 3$. For larger values of $k\le n$, the unbiased estimator of $\mu_k$ also depends on $\mu_\ell^n$ for $1\le\ell\le k-1$.

Note however that $\hat\mu_k^n$ is a converging estimator of $\mu_k$ (as $n$ grows to infinity).

[image]

Let me also point out that it is always possible to turn biased estimators into unbiased estimators if *sequential* sampling is available. Using coupling and stopping time and a telescoping sum argument, as demonstrated by Glynn and Rhee ([Exact estimation for Markov chain equilibrium expectations](https://doi.org/10.1239/jap/1417528487).*Journal of Applied Probability*, 51(A):377–389, 2014.)

Comment: In the first item in the enumeration, should "only exist when $k \leq m$" be "... $k \leq n$"?

Answer (score 1):

### General Formula

The general formula for the $n\text{th}$ moment for a function $f(x)$  (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) is

$$
\mu_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x - c)^n f(x) dx
$$

where $c = 0$ if you're calculating the first moment (the mean),
and $c = $ the mean otherwise.

With $k$ data points, this can be estimated as

$$
\hat \mu_n = E[ (x - c)^n ] = \frac{\sum_i^k(x_i - c)^n}{k}
$$

For statistical purposes, you'll want to look into the [Standardised moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_moment)

### How much data

At minimum, you need $n$ data points to have an estimate the $n$th moment. You need one to estimate the mean, 2 for the variance, 3 for skew, and so on. Obviously, these will be extremely poor estimates, since these are the absolute minima.

### Confidence Intervals

Calculating confidence intervals for higher-order moments in general is tricky. [Wright and Herrington (2011)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-010-0044-x) provide a way of estimating them using bootstrap samples.

Comment: I do not understand why one _needs_ $k$ observations for the $k$-th moment since $X_1^k$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$.

Comment: That's a fair point. My thinking is that these are the minima needed for these values to be meaningful. You can't sensibly talk about the variance of 1 value, skew of 2 values, or kurtosis of 3 values, I think?

Comment: What if we want to obtain a "good" estimate of the moments--not just a poor one?

Comment: I believe this depends on the distribution of your data. You need to decide how small you need the standard error to be to count as "good", and use the bootstrap (citation in my answer) to calculate the SE for the data you have.

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure that the denominator $k$ is correct. Since $k-1$ is the denominator for an unbiased estimate of the variance (2nd moment), maybe $k-1$ or $k-n+1$ provides a better estimate?

Comment: Dividing by $k$ returns an unbiased estimator. This is not necessarily a _"good"_ property but this is one usually sought in statistical estimation. The denominator of the variance estimator is $k-1$ because of this unbiased property, but the variance is not the second moment, being centred first.

Comment: Skewness as a moment ratio or as (mean - median) ./ SD can be calculated for a sample with two distinct values. But then it is always zero, as the two distinct values yield a mean (by definition) and a median (by convention) half-way between them. Otherwise put, a sample with two distinct values must be symmetrical about its mean and median and can convey no information about the skewness of its parent distribution.